# With the recent security issue with xz, what should we do before using Homebrew again?

Tags: macos, security, homebrew, ssh

Ars Technica's March 30, 2024 [Backdoor found in widely used Linux utility breaks encrypted SSH connections](https://arstechnica.com/security/2024/03/backdoor-found-in-widely-used-linux-utility-breaks-encrypted-ssh-connections/) includes the following:

> Several people, including two Ars readers, reported that the multiple apps included in the HomeBrew package manager for macOS rely on the backdoored 5.6.1 version of xz Utils. HomeBrew has now rolled back the utility to version 5.4.6. Maintainers have more details available [here](https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/5243#discussioncomment-8954951).

At the link in the block quote (titled "brew install xz installs the outdated version 5.4.6 instead of 5.6.1 #5243") there is talk about `brew cleanup xz --prune=0`, but I don't really understand the implications of everything there.

I may need to use `brew` to install a specific numerical Python package in about a week. Should I wait a few days for the dust to settle, or should I find a way to "clean up" or to uninstall and then reinstall Homebrew?

Comment: From the page linked from the quote: „To be clear: we don't believe Homebrew's builds were compromised (the backdoor only applied to deb and rpm builds) but 5.6.x is being treated as no longer trustworthy and as a precaution we are forcing downgrades to 5.4.6.“ Also, from looking at https://gynvael.coldwind.pl/?lang=en&id=782, it only seems to be relevant for Linux systems.

Comment: @nohillside: I believe your analysis is correct. One of the tricky bits about this backdoor is that the malicious actor inserted the code only into the distribution tarballs, so it does not show up in any reviews of the source code repository. Furthermore, the code which inserts the backdoor checks whether the build process is running as part of a distribution package build under RPM or dpkg with a clean environment (as usually on a build server), so it does not show up on manual builds or test builds either. It only gets inserted into packages that are built as part of an official Linux …

Comment: … distribution package build on a build server.

Answer (score 32):

TL,DR: **just run `brew upgrade`**.

“Just upgrade” is almost always the right answer when a security vulnerability is announced. Distribution maintainers are often notified of vulnerabilities in advance, and even when they aren't, they usually react quicker than end-users. By the time you read a press article about a vulnerability, it's usually been patched by all mainstream distributions. And if it isn't, it's usually because the patching is difficult and you probably won't manage it on your own quicker than the distribution.

As an end-user of software, you typically only need to react to a vulnerability if you installed it manually through a channel that doesn't do updates. This is one of the reasons you should install software via an app store or package manager if possible.

Needing special commands was an emergency measure while the Homebrew maintainers reacted to the vulnerability announcement. Homebrew is very reactive and all you need to do now is upgrade normally. As I write this, `brew upgrade xz` downgrades xz from 5.6.1 to 5.4.6.

At this time, no vulnerability is known in xz 5.6.1 as distributed by Homebrew (the known vulnerability was only inserted during some builds), but the Homebrew maintainers have rolled back xz in case there was another, better hidden vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

So far, there has been [no security advisory](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/security) from the brew project. Nor are there any [open issues against `xz`](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+xz).

If the risk has not been documented and addressed by the time you need the packages, install the numerical Python packages [without brew](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/).